# Understanding buffer passing via MPI_Isend and MPI_Irecv

Tags: c, unix, parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi

I want to understand how sending and receiving are processed by MPI. Suppose I allocate a buffer of [12][50] elements as the following:

```
int **buf= malloc(12 * sizeof(int *));
for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    buf[i] = malloc(50 * sizeof(int));

    // Immediatly fill each row by 1s for testing purpose. 
    for (j = 0; j < 50; j++)
    {
         buf[i][j] = 1;
    }
}
```

Now, I want to send each row to `P = 12` processors using non-blocking `MPI_Isend` and `MPI_Irecv` as the following:

```
for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    MPI_Isend(buf[i], 50, MPI_INT, i, TAG_0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req[i]); 
    MPI_Wait(&req[i], &status[i]);
}

    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        MPI_Irecv(bufRecv[i], 50, MPI_INT, MASTER, TAG_0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req[i]);
        MPI_Wait(&req[i], &status[i]);
    }
```

As far as I know, `MPI_Isend` here sends each ith row followed by 50 consecutive elements starting from the memory address stored in `but[i]` whereas `MPI_Irecv` receives the corresponding ith row and store it in `MPI_Irecv` . Am I right? If no, can someone explain why?

Thank you.

Comment: It's important that in your second code segment, only the `rank==MASTER` processor calls the `MPI_Isend`. Furthermore, each rank==i` processor should only be calling one `MPI_Irecv` to get its portion of the array, not 12. You have to be explicit about which processor is sending/receiving what; otherwise all of them will call everything - resulting in your current code as deadlocks and access to null values.

Comment: THANK YOU for this part (each rank==i processor should only be calling one MPI_Irecv to get its portion of the array,) It solves many issues and enlighten my thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right. `MPI_Irecv` would receive the message into `bufRecv`. However, your code does not really make sense. First off, a non-blocking communication call directly followed by a wait is basically the same as a blocking call.

Then the receiving part should be called on a different process, and from your description each receiver would call `MPI_Irecv` only once, not 12 times. Or, if every process is to receive all rows, the sender has to call send for each process number of rows times.

Most importantly: what you describe is covered by [MPI_Scatter](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-1.1/mpi-11-html/node71.html#Node71), no need to implement it yourself. If you want one process to send data to all processes, use [MPI_Bcast](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-1.1/mpi-11-html/node67.html#Node67).